# Why don't Nuget-added assembly versions in app.config and packages.config match?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am getting this exception for an assembly added using Nuget, in a static C# library:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
> match the assembly reference.

After checking the assembly is in the /bin folder, I noticed I have version 4.7 of the DLL. So this is what I've found out...

**Is specified in the Nuget settings**
[image]

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.7.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**properties for the assembly in project references**

[image]

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I have updated the Nuget packages and the packages.config is updated but not the app.config. I seem to have the assembly various referenced as:

- v4.7.1
- v4.0.30319
- v4.0.6.0

And then the version it's trying and failing to load is none of these, 4.0.4.1

I can't tell which of these version mis-matches matter and which is causing the problem, looking at other projects it seems fairly typical. How can I fix it?

Comment: `v4.0.30319` seems to be a runtime version

Comment: The other thing is, I have a test-harness using the same libs and everything seems identical... but that works. Seemingly every detail is the same!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I hadn't realised but that's apprently the .Net version it was built against. So seems ok. But where is 4.0.4.1 coming from?!

Comment: packages.config lists package version, which is different to assembly version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning

Comment: Also, look at note 2 under the table listed on this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support   it explicitly says that net461 has problems with .NET Standard, and it's recommended to use at least .NET Framework 4.7.2